# I need help on a 24 hr unconfirmed transaction on blockchain

Tags: blockchain

If anyone can please help I transferred $254 worth of bitcoin to my coinbase account and it has been 24 hours now and it still has 0/3 confirmations so my money is just floating out there somewhere. I'm very confused because my first transaction literally took 20 mins and it was for about the same amount. Is everything alright or do I need to worry? I see people saying stuff about raising the miner fee but from what I have seen you can't do that once it has been sent. If everything is ok and I have nothing to worry about then that's great but I'm really starting to worry here. I thought bitcoin transaction were stress free but here I'am freaking out. I can't imagine if it was a big transaction what I would do. Please Help! Has this happened to anyone? Is this normal? How do I avoid this is the future or is this completely normal (because everything I read says 30 mins)? First time poster so please take it easy on me I would appreciate it. Thank You for your time

Answer (score 1):

It's "normal" but it shouldn't be :/ https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions when this goes pretty high there is a large list of transaction that needs to process and the miners are selecting the transactions that have the largest fee density. If you want you can post your transaction here and I'll give a more detailed explanation for your specific situation. The good way to avoid this is to adjust your miner/transaction fee in consequence of the size of the backlog.

Comment: Also when this happen and it's urgent that it gets confirmed there is a "simple" way to resend the transaction with a higher miner fee.

Comment: Hi Will, welcome to the site.  We've been getting a very large number of similar questions lately and we're trying to direct everyone to  the "canonical" question http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it .  If there's something those answers don't cover, please add a new answer to that question.  That way we keep all our knowledge in one accessible place instead of fragmented across the site.

Comment: So Will what do I need to do it's been 30 hours now. Do I just copy and paste the transaction number to here or what exactly do you need from me? I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Also Will is there a way to cancel a transaction and have it go back to your blockchain account? From what I have read on here some say you can and some say you can't. I also couldn't find much info on advanced sending. So what is the normal miner fee and what amount would make it go through instantly?